# PHP MySQL consolidate column where other column has duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, unique

I have a MySQL table that has three columns, the first is a unique key (`INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT`), the next is an indexed value (`VARCHAR(255)`) and the third is a description (`TEXT`). There are duplicate values in the second column, but each row has a different description. I want to remove all rows where the second column is duplicated but append each description of the same indexed value to the first instance the value, and breaking string with a semicolon and space.

For example, my table looks like this:

```
cid   | word    | description
------------------------------
1     | cat     | an animal with wiskers
2     | cat     | a house pet
3     | dog     | a member of the canine family
4     | cat     | a cool person
```

I want to change the table to look like this:

```
cid   | word    | description
------------------------------
1     | cat     | an animal with wiskers; a house pet; a cool person
3     | dog     | a member of the canine family
```

I'm not adverse to using a PHP script to do this, but would prefer MySQL. The table has over 170,000 rows and would take PHP a long time to loop over it.

Comment: MySQL 5.7 will complain about `cid` here since there's no logic for how you're picking that number. Is it the lowest `cid` value? Can that column be omitted in your alternate view?

Answer (score 2):

SQL:

```
select `cid`,`word`,group_concat(`description` SEPARATOR '; ') as `description` from `test_table` group by `word`;
```

Ok.. you can copy all the data into another table, and rename it then..

```
insert into `test_new` (`cid`,`word`,`desc`) (select `cid`,`word`,group_concat(`desc` SEPARATOR '; ') as `description` from `test_table` group by `word`);

mysql> describe `test_new`;
+-------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| word  | char(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| desc  | text     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from `test_new`;
+------+------+---------------------+
| id   | word | desc                |
+------+------+---------------------+
|    1 | cat  | desc1; desc2; desc4 |
|    3 | dog  | desc3               |
+------+------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: After having used that SQL code, how might you create another table with the information that is selected?

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned before, you can create a new table and copy the info, you can also do it in two steps, but only if there´s no problem with modifying the old table:

```
UPDATE tableOld AS N1, tableOld AS N2 
SET N1.description = concat(concat(N1.description,"; "),N2.decription))
WHERE N2.word = N1.word

insert into tableNew (cid,name,description)select * from tableOld group by word
```