# Insert many rows from a table into one unique row in another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, foreach, row

I have a table named `order` where there is set a column name `list`

```
TABLE list
id |  list      | price    | date
---------------------------------------
1  | Cigar      |  5.00    | 2016-06-30
2  | Beer       |  6.00    | 2016-06-30
3  | Whiskey    |  20.00   | 2016-06-30
4  | Bacon      |  10.00   | 2016-06-30
```

I'd like to insert the `list` into another table named `confirmation` in a way that all of them could be in a same row! However, it doesn't work and is inserting in many rows!

The way I want

```
TABLE confirmation
id |            theorder             
--------------------------------
1  | Cigar, Beer, Whiskey, Bacon
```

The way is showing

```
TABLE confirmation
id |  theorder      
--------------
1  | Cigar,
2  | Beer,
3  | Whiskey,
4  | Bacon,
```

Here is the code: I'm working with foreach!

```
$sql     = "SELECT list FROM order";
$result  = $conn->query($sql);
$getList = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach($getOrder as $order) {
  $products = $order['theorder'] . ', ';
  $sql      = "INSERT INTO confirmation (theorder) VALUES ('$products')";
  $result   = $conn->query($sql);
}
```

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36781495/php-mysql-consolidate-column-where-other-column-has-duplicates) is similar question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you perform an `INSERT` query it creates a new row. Since you're doing this in a loop, it creates a new row for each product.

If you want to combine items, use `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
INSERT INTO confirmation (theorder)
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(list SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM `order`
```

Notice that you need to quote the table name `order` with backticks because it's a reserved word. It's generally best to avoid using reserved words as table and column names, since if you forget to quote it you'll get a confusing syntax error. See [Syntax error due to using a reserved word as a table or column name in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446377/syntax-error-due-to-using-a-reserved-word-as-a-table-or-column-name-in-mysql/23446378#23446378)

Comment: Right. This SQL query will do the whole thing.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try and rate it soon! =D

Comment: @CaioFerrari , I suspect you will need group by date.

Comment: @Wizard I suspect so as well. But his original code doesn't filter by date, it just gets all the orders.

Comment: @Barmar just a little question: how can I mix the answer you've typed with adding new values? Does exist something like this?

`INSERT INTO confirmation (theorder, theprice, thedate) SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(list SEPARATOR ', ') VALUES ($theprice, $thedate) FROM 'order'`

Comment: You can put literals in the `SELECT` list: `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(list SEPARATOR ', '), '$theprice', '$thedate' FROM order`